# Access 2010 No records returned based on date/time field

Tags: datetime, ms-access, select

I must be brain dead today because I cannot get any records to return in a SELECY query.  I'm trying to select records for the last 30 days (since 2/8/2016).  I know there are records in the database since 2/8/16.  This is my selection criteria:  >#2/7/2016 11:59:59 PM#.  I'm not sure why I'm not getting any records.  I've looked at the table and the field I'm trying to select on is Date/Time (General Date format).  Any suggestions would be appreciated as this is making me crazy.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just use the date part of it, without the time. So...

> =#2/8/2016#

If this is to be variable date for the last 30 days from today, you could also write it as

> =Now()-30

Hope this helps.

Josetta

Comment: I was using the first suggestion and didn't get any results.  I rebuilt the query and it worked.  A lot of strange things lately.  Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Use this criteria for your date field:

```
>=DateAdd("d",-30,Date())
```

or for a specific date:

```
>=DateAdd("d",-30,DateSerial(2016,3,1))
```

or, if 30 days means a month:

```
>=DateAdd("m",-1,Date())
```

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I'll try that